# In Nougat, cannot detect Network connectivity changes when the app is force closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I want to detect network changes in all cases(App in the background, foreground and also when not running).

Am doing some syncing process in background using service in my application. When the device connected to the internet, using CONNECTIVITY_ACTION receiver will start the background syncing process.This is working on below nougat version.

Below Nougat, using CONNECTIVITY_ACTION we can detect connectivity changes when the app is in background, foreground and even when the app is not running.

From Nougat, as from documentation :

"Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare their broadcast receiver in the manifest. Apps will still receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid."

I cannot detect broadcast when the app is not running even though I removed registering receiver from the manifest and done manual register and unregister in Activity class.

I have used below code in my activity,

```
    IntentFilter  intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver( new NetworkChangeReceiver(), intentFilter); // NetworkChangeReceiver() is class extends BroadcastReceiver
```

Comment: Have you tried keeping your `NetworkChangeReceiver` as a class instance instead?

Comment: If your app isn't running, then there is no instance of your `NetworkChangeReceiver` registered to receive broadcasts. That quote from the documentation does not mean that a dynamically registered Receiver instance completely replaces the functionality of a statically registered class. It means that you can now only get that broadcast while your app is running.